# Как из строки вытащить значения? (PHP)

Tags: php

Есть сторка например 'id=22 tmpl=default' как разделить/вытащить значения?

мой не рабочий вариант(

```
$id    = trim(preg_replace("/.*?id.*?=/i", "", trim($string)));
$tmpl  = trim(preg_replace("/.*?tmpl.*?=/i", "", trim($string)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
<?php
    $unformated = 'id=22 tmpl=default'; //исходная строка. данные разделены пробелами
    $exploded = explode(' ', $unformated); //сначала разделим все пары ключ-значение

    $data = []; //пустой массив, мы его заполним данными

    foreach ($exploded as $row) { //пробежимся по всем разделенным данным
        $keyvalue = explode('=', $row); //разделим по знаку =
        $data[$keyvalue[0]] = $keyvalue[1]; //добавим в массив ключ до = значение после =
    }

    // Вот что получилось
    echo 'Теперь у нас массив данных:<br>';
    print_r($data); //выводим массив

    echo "<hr>Можем вывести значение по ключу: значение tmpl в массиве равно: ".$data['tmpl'];
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш вариант наиболее подходит для меня!

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php)

```php
<?php

$str = 'id=22 tmpl=default';

$result = [];
$rexp = '/([\w]+)=([^\s]+)/u';

$status = preg_match_all($rexp, $str, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);

if ($status !== FALSE)
{
    echo "Found $status matches:" . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($result);
}
else
{
    echo "Error in test";
}
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/qdFhbY)

```php
Found 2 matches:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id=22
            [1] => id
            [2] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => tmpl=default
            [1] => tmpl
            [2] => default
        )

)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Длинноват массив получается)

Comment: Но исполнение наверно наиболее легкое!